# I want a GRT tokens faucet site or any link where I can buy these testnet

Tags: metamask, testnets, faucets, the-graph, subgraph

I want a Graph-Token (GRT) faucet site or any link where I can buy these testnet.

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot add a comment to ask you to elaborate on your question, so I hope I understood you correctly.

You want Graph-Token on testnet to test *The Graph* features etc'.

I checked and they have in their docs, an explanation that you need both ETH & GRT - and provided this guide([source](https://docs.thegraph.academy/the-graph-ecosystem/infrastructure/testnet#testnet-https-testnet.thegraph.com-goerli)):

1. Join The Graph Discord server
2. Get the @testnetindexer role in the #roles channel
3. Use the #testnet-goerli-faucet channel to obtain testnet GRT.